# Is there any way to fix topomap plot with mne library in python?

Tags: python, image, mne-python

I am trying to plot topo map with mne library, but I don't know why the figure does not contain contour/outlier and nose and ears. Anyone can help me with this issue?
My code is here:

```
import mne
fname = "oddball-epo.fif"

epochs = mne.read_epochs(fname,preload=True)

target = epochs["target"].average()
target

standard = epochs["standard"].average()

target.plot_joint()

times = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
times1 = [-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
target.plot_joint(times)
target.plot_topomap(times1, ch_type='eeg')
target.plot_joint(times1)
```

It is the resulting image
[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwekJ.png)
& Expected result
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLAeY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a plotting problem, you can adjust the topomap settings by passing a dict **topomap_args** to **plot_joint**. What defines the outlines is the "outlines" argument that can be either "skirt" or "head". All topomap arguments can be found in the [documentation](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.Evoked.html?highlight=plot_topomap#mne.Evoked.plot_topomap).

```
target.plot_joint(topomap_args = {'outlines':'skirt'})
```

If that doesn't solve it, it's probably a problem of the sensors template, check if it is correct:

```
epochs.plot_sensors()
```

If it's not as you expect it to be, you can fix it by setting a new montage ([available options](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.channels.make_standard_montage.html#mne.channels.make_standard_montage))

```
epochs.info.set_montage('standard_1020')
```